# Test text input with react and jest

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs, react-bootstrap

I have a simple [SearchBar](https://github.com/runjak/spreadshirtRemoteTask/blob/master/src/Searchbar.js) component in a small test project of mine.
This SearchBar consists mainly of a text input and a button,
where the button click executes a callback with the text from the input field.

My [Searchbar.render](https://github.com/runjak/spreadshirtRemoteTask/blob/master/src/Searchbar.js#L23-L42) method looks like this:

```
  return (
    <FormGroup controlId="keywords">
      <InputGroup>
        <FormControl type="text"
                     placeholder="Keywords…"
                     value={this.state.keywords}
                     onChange={this.updateKeywords} />
        <InputGroup.Button
          onClick={() => {this.props.onSearch(this.state.keywords);}}
          ref="searchInput">
          <Button ref="searchButton">
            <Glyphicon glyph="search"/>
          </Button>
        </InputGroup.Button>
      </InputGroup>
    </FormGroup>
  );
```

I've written a [test](https://github.com/runjak/spreadshirtRemoteTask/blob/master/src/Searchbar.test.js#L13-L34) for it using jest:

```
it("should adjust keywords and trigger onSearch correctly", () => {
  const handleSearch = jest.fn();

  const searchBar = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
    <Searchbar onSearch={handleSearch}/>
  );
  expect(searchBar.state.keywords).toBe("");

  const button = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(searchBar.refs.searchButton);
  const input = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(searchBar.refs.searchInput);

  ReactTestUtils.Simulate.change(input, {target: {value: "test"}});

  ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click(button);
  expect(handleSearch).toHaveBeenCalledWith("test");
});
```

Now the callback in this test works and the function stored in `callMe` get's called as expected. The `SearchBar` also works in my application so I think that the `SearchBar` code is correct. But when I use `npm test` to run my tests the test fails with:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expected)

Expected mock function to have been called with:
  ["test"]
But it was called with:
  [""]
```

In the comments [Andreas Köberle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/184883/andreas-k%C3%B6berle) pointed me to the problem that the `updateKeywords` method appears to not be called which should be the reason for the failing test. Sadly I cannot figure out why this method isn't called in the test.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the event data by yourself, as it does not really trigger the event on a DOM element. From the docs:

> You will have to provide any event property that you're using in your
>   component (e.g. keyCode, which, etc...) as React is not creating any
>   of these for you.

Is also common to just put a spy function as callback into your component, and test this after simulate the event.

```
const handleSearch = jest.fn();
const searchBar = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
    <Searchbar onSearch={handleSearch}/>
);
ReactTestUtils.Simulate.change(input, {target: {value: 'test'}});
expect(handleSearch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test')
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer!
Sadly it doesn't work so far.
I've adjusted my [Searchbar.test.js](https://github.com/runjak/spreadshirtRemoteTask/blob/master/src/Searchbar.test.js#L27) but `npm test` still complains. I've adjusted my `master` branch in the hope to make this easier to reproduce.

Comment: Nice, I wasn't aware of the `toHaveBeenCalledWith` method. This is more elegant, but my test still fails. I've updated the question and master branch accordingly.

Comment: I would suggest to debug this by adding a `log` into the `updateKeywords` method to check that it is called.

Comment: Hm. It appears that your lead is right. The `updateKeywords` function appears to not be called in the test. But it is called in the browser. I don't get what's up with this, but will investigate further.